# PHP request variables are empty when textarea contains <script> tag

Tags: php, apache, tags, textarea

I have a form on my website to allow user to insert content for dynamically generated pages on my website. The form along with other controls has a textarea where user is required to type/paste html code to be used as body of the page.
The form seems to work fine as long as the textarea doesn't contain "script" tag. When html code containing script tag is pasted and form is submitted, the request seems to be killed by the server, the $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST variables are empty. The code works fine on my windows testing machine (WAMP 5.xx) however, where the website is hosted(Linux hosted) the code won't work.
I've read in similar questions, someone posted the following code in .htaccess file would help, but it doesn't help in my case:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
     SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

It appears there is some configuration issue, i've also checked phpinfo() for both systems and there is no significant difference.
Please help, the site needs to go live within this week.

Comment: How about `SecFilterScanPOST Off` as well?

Comment: mod_security is not installed on my host, therefore any inside that tag won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering <string> tags before submitting? A client side Javascript could do the trick.
Maybe regexes could help. This way you don't have to work on server configuration and you do not compromise security

Comment: I don't want to filter the scripts, I want them to be available in the php posted variables.

Comment: If you filter them up before submitting (catching submit events) then you can unfilter them after you got them as a POST variable. A fast example: client-side: turn <string> into {{string}}; server-side: return {{string}} into <string>;
With those strings filtered before submit apache won't filter them up.

Comment: looks like a good idea but, the problem persists if javascript is disabled on client-side hence a partial fix.

Comment: Yes, this is just a workaround if you can't change your host's configuration, but are there so many "disabled javascript browsers" out there, and do they usually post <script> data around?

Comment: I'm not sure how they do that, but if there is some configuration that needs to be tweaked I can ask my hosting provider to do that for me. The thing is I don't know which configuration needs to be tweaked?

Comment: btw, have you any idea how does wordpress handle users generating custom pages?

Comment: Nope, sorry, maybe you need to post a new question about that.

Comment: can u provide the regex to do what you were saying earlier? May be I can hang with a temporary solution untill i find a robust one.

Comment: Just replace "<script>" with "{{script}}" and "</script>" with "{{/script}".
Another way to proceed maybe replacing every tag with this regex:
var re = new RegExp("<(.*)>", "g");
var myArray = str.replace(re,"{{$1}}" ); //where str is the string you get from the textarea
After this you can get the original string back replacing {{(.*)}} with <$1>